# Access all (user) accounts inside Keychain

Tags: ios, keychain

I've been looking all around but still not found the answer. Any idea how to return all kSecAttrAccounts from keychain? I would like to get back a list of every identifier I used when creating keychain items, then to choose the one I want to delete it using a "[KeychainWrapper deleteItemFromKeychainWithIdentifier:identifier] method".

It works fine when I remember the username (identifier) I used when creating the account but cannot figure out how to have them all back when you created lots of them.

I tried a kind of basic [dictionary objectForKey:(__bridge(id)kSecAttrAccount)] but it does not make it.

Thanks a lot!!

Tricho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `kSecMatchLimitAll` to get all values in your query dictionary for `kSecMatchLimit`

```
 (__bridge id)kSecMatchLimitAll, (__bridge id)kSecMatchLimit
```

It will fetch all passwords in keychain for `kSecClassGenericPassword`.You can use other `keychain classes` as well like this

```
NSMutableDictionary *query = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    (__bridge id)kCFBooleanTrue, (__bridge id)kSecReturnAttributes,
    (__bridge id)kSecMatchLimitAll, (__bridge id)kSecMatchLimit,
    (__bridge id)kSecClassGenericPassword, (__bridge id)kSecClass, //change your class in query
    nil];

    CFTypeRef result = NULL;
    SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)query, &result);
    NSLog(@"%@", (__bridge id)result);
    if (result != NULL) CFRelease(result);
```

**EDIT** : For delting all keys of your app you can use

```
+(void)deleteAllKeychainItems{


    NSArray *secItemClasses = @[(__bridge id)kSecClassGenericPassword,
                                (__bridge id)kSecClassInternetPassword,
                                (__bridge id)kSecClassCertificate,
                                (__bridge id)kSecClassKey,
                                (__bridge id)kSecClassIdentity];
    for (id secItemClass in secItemClasses) {
        NSDictionary *spec = @{(__bridge id)kSecClass:secItemClass};
        SecItemDelete((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)spec);
    }

}
```

It will delete all `keychain` items including all accounts password or values associated.

Comment: Do you mean something like NSMutableDictionary* query = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:(__bridge id)kSecMatchLimitAll, (__bridge id)kSecMatchLimit, nil];? Not sure how to deal with what you said...

Comment: edited my answer have a look.For which class you want to get the keychain items?

Comment: @codester just asking for learning purpose, is it allowed to access all keychain items even it is written from another app?

Comment: no you can not access the other apps key-chain items unless they belong to same access group.You can access your and your `access group` apps(group of app belongs to same group to share data) and it is also depend on your app to which data shared to other apps.

Comment: @codester oh that is ok, when I see question I thought how. thanks.

Comment: I am using methods using identifier to deal with items (like the "deleteFromKeychain...:identifier" above). I would like to fetch all identifiers (which should be the values of kSecAttrAccount I think). Probably I have to change the class (kSecAttrAccount instead of your kSecClassGenericPassword) in your example and it will return every accounts?

Comment: See how you are saving the keychain items for which class,use same query with `kSecMatchLimitAll` key to find and delete the item.`kSecAttrAccount` specifies account and it is not a class.So you can not use it in place of `kSecClassGenericPassword`

Comment: Okay I will have a try. Thanks a lot by the way!

Comment: Can you post the code of saving the items in keychain. you can not able to use `kSecAttrAccount` in place of kSecClassGenericPassword as `kSecAttrAccount` no a class

Comment: use `(__bridge id)kSecMatchLimitAll, (__bridge id)kSecMatchLimit
` in delete query.It will make to delete all items

Comment: + (BOOL)createKeychainValue:(NSString *)value forIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier {
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [self setupSearchDirectoryForIdentifier:identifier];
NSData *valueData = [value dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[dictionary setObject:valueData forKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData];
    
[dictionary setObject:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlocked forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessible];
    
OSStatus status = SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)dictionary, NULL);

Comment: if (status == errSecSuccess) { return YES;} else if (status == errSecDuplicateItem){ return [self updateKeychainValue:value forIdentifier:identifier];} else {return NO;}}